# How to adjust mouse over div according to screen size?

Tags: html, css, jquery, screen

On Quora, on mouseOvering a username/ picture, a card pops up which is always inside the window display area. It's position gets adjusted according to the screen size.

E.g. in these [Quora screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfWJV.jpg), the first image is when the screen has a higher resolution, and the second image is when I have zoomed in. The hover card comes on the right the first time, but on the left in the 2nd.

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You do this by looking at the left pos and width of the popup, and the width of the screen, and comparing the two. Then if the left pos of the popup plus the width of the popup is more than the screen width, you set the left pos of the popup to the screen width minus the width of the popup. Make sense? An implementation (this happens to be jQuery, but you'll get the idea...):

```
    function adjustPos(menu) {
        var menuHeight = $('#' + menu).outerHeight();
        var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
        if ((menuY + menuHeight) > bodyHeight) {
            menuY = bodyHeight - menuHeight;
        }
        var menuWidth = $('#' + menu).outerWidth();
        var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        if ((menuX + menuWidth) > bodyWidth) {
            menuX = bodyWidth - menuWidth;
        }
    }
```

Remember that you need to do it for height as well.

Comment: In your mouseover event, pass the event to the function. Then use event.pageX to get the mouse position. The adjust that x and y based on page width as per above. Then set your css top/left with the adjusted values.